# How to query my locally-hosted ORS backend for directions using the openrouteservice R package

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, openrouteservice

I am using the `openrouteservice` `R` package to access the directions endpoint of ORS API.
I set my API key as follows:

```
Sys.setenv(OPENROUTESERVICE_KEY = <my_api_key>)
```

Then I go on to query the API using the `ors_directions()` function.

This works fine.

But I have now setup my locally-hosted ORS backend and I would like to query it instead of the public one.

what changes do I make to my code?

I have set up my **base_url** like this:
`options(openrouteservice.url = "http://localhost:8080/ors/v2")`

Unfortunately, when I run `ors_directions()`, I still get the message: `Error: Not Found (HTTP 404)`.

My backend is running well. I can already test it using the API request in the browser like this for instance and it returns proper directions: `http://localhost:8080/ors/v2/directions/driving-car?start=30.05793,-1.972133&end=29.531427,-1.712719`

Comment: Please have a look on https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-r and `options(openrouteservice.url = "http://localhost:8080/ors")`

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko What do you think is the issue, I have already test your suggestion and it is not working still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get a workaround.
The key is to use `Sys.env()` instead of `options()`.
So, in my case, replacing the options() call with:
`Sys.setenv(ORS_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/ors/v2")`

Worked!